# Django change database field from integer to CharField

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django app with a populated (Postgres) database that has an integer field that I need to change to a CharField. I need to start storing data with leading zeros in this field. If I run migrate (Django 1.8.4), I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer

HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried searching Google, but didn't really find much help. I don't really know what I'm supposed to do here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you backup the table, drop the faulty table, recreate it then re-import the data? As tedious as it seems; it will work.

Comment: Can you just change the name of the field by prepending with and underscore, then make a method with the original field name that does the zero-padding for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Originally, I thought that there would be a simple solution where Django or Postgres would do the conversion automatically, but it appears that it doesn't work that way. I think some of suggestions made by others might have worked, but I came up with a simple solution of my own. This was done on a production database so I had to be careful. I ended up adding the character field to the model and did the migration. I then ran a small script in the python shell that copied the data in the integer field, did the conversion that I needed, then wrote that to the new field in the same record in the production database.

for example:

```
members = Members.objects.all()
for mem in members:
    mem.memNumStr = str(mem.memNum)
    ... more data processing here
    mem.save()
```

So now, I had the data duplicated in the table in a str field and an int field. I could then modify the views that accessed that field and test it on the production database without breaking the old code. Once that is done, I can drop the old int field. A little bit involved, but pretty simple in the end.

Comment: This answer gets you most of the way there. To complete the solution you also want to include parts of the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33191630/1914918
To put it all together:
1. Add a new field to the model (`memNumOld`). This will be the old integral field. Change the existing field to be a CharField.
2. To a new migration, add a `migrations.RenameField('members', 'memNum', 'memNumOld')`
3. To that migration, also add a `migrations.AddField(... 'memNum' ...)`
4. Finally add a `migrations.RunPython` that calls the scriptlet above

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to generate a schema migration. How you do that will depend on which version of Django you are using (versions 1.7 and newer have built-in migrations; older versions of Django will use `south`).

*Of Note*: if this data is production data, you'll want to be very careful with how you proceed. Make sure you have a known good copy of your data you can reinstall if things get hairy. Test your migrations in a non-production environment. Be. Careful!

As for the transformation on the field (from IntegerField to CharField) and the transformation on the field values (to be prepended with leading zeroes) - Django cannot do this for you, you'll have to write this manually. The proper way to do this is to use the `django.db.migrations.RunPython` migration command ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython)).

My advice would be to generate multiple migrations; one that creates a new IntegerField, `my_new_column` and then write to this new column via RunPython. Then, run a second migration that removes the original CharField `my_old_column` and renames `my_new_column` as `my_old_column`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed (and very prompt) answer, but I came up with a solution that worked out better for me. But I think that your solution will be informative for others. It was for me.

Comment: @mpsg As far as I can tell, this is essentially the same as the solution you wrote in your own answer. The main difference is that cucksmash suggests that you do these as migrations so that they can be more easily reproduced if needed.

Answer (score 3):

from django 2.x you just need to change the field type from

```
 IntegerField to CharField
```

and django will automatically alter field and migrate data as well for you.

Comment: I don't think that is true, and cannot find any documentation that says so. Can you kindly link to the official documentation where your claim "automatic alter field" can be verified?

Comment: I was going the other way in 2.2, but I was able to just change CharField to IntegerField and run migrate, and everything worked fine.

Comment: I've used django 2.1.4  simply changing type doesn't helped me,  (error raised django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
 ) 

so I guess you had an empty data ?

Comment: Just tried to change the field from IntegerField to CharField in Django 2.1. The migration worked just find and the new CharField held the previous integer values as strings. Obviously Django did an implicit type conversion. To make the migration reversable I will have to add an translation of the previous IntegerValues to meaningful strings and back.

Comment: Works in Django 3.1 !

Answer (score 2):

I thought a full code example would be helpful.  I followed the approach outlined by ken-koster in the comment above.  I ended up with two migrations (0091 and 0092).  It seems that the two migrations could be squashed into one migration but I did not go that far.  (Maybe Django does this automatically but the framework here could be used in case the string values are more complicated than a simple int to string conversion.  Also I included a reverse conversion example.)

First migration (0091):

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0090_auto_20200622_1452'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # store original values in tmp fields
        migrations.RenameField(model_name='member',
                               old_name='mem_num',
                               new_name='mem_num_tmp'),
        # add back fields as string fields
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='member',
            name='mem_num',
            field=models.CharField(default='0', max_length=64, verbose_name='Number of members'),
        ),
    ]
```

Second migration (0092):

```
from django.db import migrations

def copyvals(apps, schema_editor):
    Member = apps.get_model("myapp", "Member")
    members = Member.objects.all()
    for member in members:
        member.rotate_xy = str(member.mem_num_tmp)
        member.save()

def copyreverse(apps, schema_editor):
    Member = apps.get_model("myapp", "Member")
    members = Member.objects.all()
    for member in members:
        try:
            member.mem_num_tmp = int(member.mem_num)
            member.save()
        except Exception:
            print("Reverse migration for member %s failed." % member.name)
            print(member.mem_num)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0091_custom_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # convert integers to strings
        migrations.RunPython(copyvals, reverse_code=copyreverse),

        # remove the tmp field
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='member',
            name='mem_num_tmp',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution and worked for me! I just note there are two typos in the above codes that need to be fixed: 1) `member.save()` in copyvals() needs to be indented inside the for loop. 2) the `except Exception:` block in copyreverse() needs to be indented with its `try`.