# How can i set a default value to an OneToOneField relationship which it's automatically generated?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two model classes they like below:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Place(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Author(Place):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

But when i want to execute makemigartions django shows me error below:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'place_ptr' to author without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

I have some data in Author table but i dont want to remove that data.

is there anyone could help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the old migrations file or entire migration folder for the specific app and then do the `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`
If this is not the solution you wanted then [you can find the solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498140/migrating-django-model-field-name-change-without-losing-data)

Comment: it does all migration process but there seems to be a problem place table is not generated in my database. in migrate log it shows:   

book/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Place
    - Create model Author

Comment: in database table name will be in the form of ```<app_name>_<model_name>```. Do you look at that?

Comment: no i didnt find that. aslo i try to fetch Place data model from database by executing Place.objects.all() but it shows me  django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: book_place