# How can change the primary key in a django model so that other dependent models are also affected and the changes are synced to the postgresql db

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, backend

I have a django project with a database table that already contains data.
The models:

```
class Foo_A(models.Model):
    field1_pk = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    field2
    .
    .
    fieldN_newpk = model.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Data in `field1_pk` and `fieldN_newpk` are exactly the same.
Lets say I have other models that reference `fieldN_newpk` as foreign key.

- I would like to rename a `fieldN_newpk` in this `Foo_A` model, without losing any data. This change should also be reflected in my other dependent models.
- I want to change the primary key from `field1_pk` to `fieldN_newpk`
- I want these changes to be reflected in my postgresql database as well

I have seen other answers related to renaming of a [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498140/migrating-django-model-field-name-change-without-losing-data)

**Also Is there a safe way/safe mode to try out these changes/migrations before actually trying on the original codebase**