# Django South editing field names in model with --auto --update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

In the [South Docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html),when changing the name of a field it wants you to use `./manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto --update`. When I use it I get the following`./manage.py: error: no such option: --update`. also when checking the possible options I can use update is not in there.

options given:

`--add-field=   --add-model=   --empty        --help         --pythonpath=  --stdout       --verbosity= --add-index=   --auto         --freeze=      --initial      --settings=    --traceback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is simple, do it without `--update`. When you issue `schemamigration southtut --auto` it should automatically acknowledge the changes and notice that a field has changed a name and do what it has to.

It has worked for me.

Besides what `--update` does is update the last migration instead of creating a new one so is probably not what you want. What you want is to change the schema.

If you want to rename a field in the model, you probably will have to dome something like create a migration that add the new field with the new name, then create a data migration to add the data from the old field (the one you wanna change the name) to the new field (the one with the new name) and then create a third migration to remove the old column.

You can search how to do data migration in the [south doc](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html).

You can try also what it is in this very [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235995/django-how-to-rename-a-model-field-using-south). It might be simpler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried but, my column names haven't changed with just that, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you issued the command, what does it said? When it detects that nothing has changed South says something like: "No changes". If not, it will do the changes. What was the output of the command?

Comment: well it said it deleted the column(a) and made a new one(b), but when I go to create a model object it says the column that was supposed to be deleted(a) cant be null?

Comment: Added some more info about field renaming in my answer. Hope it helps.