# How can one change the type of a Django model field from CharField to ForeignKey?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, database-migration

I need to change the type of a field in one of my Django models from `CharField` to `ForeignKey`. The fields are already populated with data, so I was wondering what is the best or right way to do this. Can I just update the field type and migrate, or are there any possible 'gotchas' to be aware of? **N.B.**: I just use vanilla Django management operations (`makemigrations` and `migrate`), not South.

Comment: Watch out for duplicate values if you don't have a unique constraint on the CharField? It really depends whether you were duplicating data before, or just want to move it out to its own table. If the latter, the best thing to do really depends on what your data MEANS. Django can't infer some kind of magic conversion between CharField and ForeignKey. You'll have to write a sensible migration yourself.

Comment: I think this is similar to what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373906/changing-the-django-data-type-in-models-without-droping-the-table

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is likely a case where you want to do a multi-stage migration. My recommendation for this would look something like the following.

First off, let's assume this is your initial model, inside an application called `discography`:

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, you realize that you want to use a ForeignKey for the artist instead. Well, as mentioned, this is not just a simple process for this. It has to be done in several steps.

Step 1, add a new field for the ForeignKey, making sure to mark it as null:

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist_link = models.ForeignKey('Artist', null=True)

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

...and create a migration for this change.

```
./manage.py makemigrations discography
```

Step 2, populate your new field. In order to do this, you have to create an empty migration.

```
./manage.py makemigrations --empty --name transfer_artists discography
```

Once you have this empty migration, you want to add a single `RunPython` operation to it in order to link your records. In this case, it could look something like this:

```
def link_artists(apps, schema_editor):
    Album = apps.get_model('discography', 'Album')
    Artist = apps.get_model('discography', 'Artist')
    for album in Album.objects.all():
        artist, created = Artist.objects.get_or_create(name=album.artist)
        album.artist_link = artist
        album.save()
```

Now that your data is transferred to the new field, you could actually be done and leave everything as is, using the new field for everything. Or, if you want to do a bit of cleanup, you want to create two more migrations.

For your first migration, you will want to delete your original field, `artist`. For your second migration, rename the new field `artist_link` to `artist`.

This is done in multiple steps to ensure that Django recognizes the operations properly. You could create a migration manually to handle this, but I will leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and comprehensive response. This has also stimulated me to finally sit down and properly learn about Django migrations!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `./manage.py makemigrations --empty ...`, though? Step 2 has `makemigration` (singular).

Comment: Thank you, i only need --empty on my makemigrations between in the two apps

Comment: I prefer to transfer data in pure python scripts, but change database schema in django migrations.

Comment: Joey I added an aswer that you might want to consider copying to complement yours, perhaps. Feel free to do so.

Answer (score 25):

Adding on top of Joey's answer, detailed steps for Django 2.2.11.

Here are the models from my use case, that consists of a `Company` and `Employee` model. We have to convert `designation` to a foreign key field. The app name is called `core`

```
class Company(CommonFields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True

class Employee(CommonFields):
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Step 1**

Create a foreign key `designation_link` in Employee and mark it as null=True

```
class Designation(CommonFields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Employee(CommonFields):
    company = models.ForeignKey("Company", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    designation_link = models.ForeignKey("Designation", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Step 2**

Create empty migration. Using the command:

`python app_code/manage.py makemigrations --empty --name transfer_designations core`

This will create a following file in `migrations` directory.

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.11 on 2020-04-02 05:56

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0006_auto_20200402_1119'),
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

**Step 3**

Populate the empty migration with a function that loops over all `Employees`, creates a `Designation` and links it to the `Employee`.

In my use case each `Designation` is also linked to a `Company`. Which means that `Designation` may contain two rows for "managers", one for company A, another for company B.

Final migration would look something like this:

```
# core/migrations/0007_transfer_designations.py

# Generated by Django 2.2.11 on 2020-04-02 05:56

from django.db import migrations

def link_designation(apps, schema_editor):
    Employee = apps.get_model('core', 'Employee')
    Designation = apps.get_model('core', 'Designation')
    for emp in Employee.objects.all():
        if(emp.designation is not None and emp.company is not None):
            desig, created = Designation.objects.get_or_create(name=emp.designation, company=emp.company)
            emp.designation_link = desig
            emp.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('core', '0006_auto_20200402_1119'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(link_designation),
    ]
```

**Step 4**

Finally run this migration using:

`python app_code/manage.py migrate core 0007`

Comment: Well explained @jerrymouse

Comment: Upvoted for explicitly adding ```migrations.TunPython(link_designation)```

Answer (score 6):

That's a continuation of the great answer by Joey.
**How to rename the new field to the original name?**

If the field has data, it probably means that you are using it elsewhere in your project, therefore this solution will leave you with a field named differently, and you have to either refactor the project to use the new field or delete the old field and rename the new one.

Be aware that this process is not going to prevent you to refactor code. If you where using a CharField with CHOICES, you were accessing its content with *get_filename_display()*, for example.

If you try to delete the field to make a migration, for then renaming the other field and make another migration, you'll see Django complaining because you cannot delete a field that you are using in the project.

Just create an empty migration as Joey explained, and put this in operations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='app_name',
        name='old_field_name',
    ),
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='app_name',
        old_name='old_field_name_link',
        new_name='old_field_name',
    ),
]
```

Then run migrate and you'll have the changes made in your database, but obviously not in your model, it's time now to delete the old field and to rename new ForeignKey field to the original name.

I don't think that doing this is particularly hacky, but still, only do this kind of things if you are fully understanding what are you messing with.