# Refactoring a field and it's references in Django

Tags: sql, django, model-view-controller, orm, refactoring

I have a model that is as follows:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   make =  models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("car make"), blank=True)
```

I now need to refactor this so that `make` becomes a class of it's own.

```
class Car(models.Model):
   make =  ForeignKey(CarMake, verbose_name=_("car make"), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

One way I thought of was changing make to `legacy_make` and adding a new field, `_make`, and then a property / getter, but it doesn't work (I understand you can't do queries this way?)

Is the best ways really to

a) Migrate old data to use new `make` class or

b) Change all references to take into account possible new car make if it is present

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the charfield to a foreignkey and migrate the data according to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000084/3553653