# Migrating Django TextChoices to IntegerChoices

Tags: django, django-models

In Django (3.2.8), I have a set of TextChoices, which I would like to change to IntegerChoices. I will keep the keys the same, just the values in the database stored will just differ. I do this for consistency and I'm fixing some legacy code.
Naturally, I changed the TextChoices to IntegerChoices, and the corresponding field to an IntegerField. As expected however, upon migrating, I get a django.db.utils.DataError: `invalid input syntax for type integer: "option1"`. I feel like there should be a way that I can define a mapping for this migration to happen, but wasn't able to find any documentation on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117564/set-django-integerfield-by-choices-name this will lead to your answer

Comment: Not in the slightest. I know how to set up TextChoices or IntegerChoices from scratch. However, I have a populated DB with TextChoices that I want to change into IntegerChoices.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use an intermediate migration. In the first migration, you add `myfield_as_int`. You migrate all the data from your old column to this new column. Then, in a second migration, you remove the old field + rename the one you created in the first migration. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35999186/change-type-of-django-model-field-from-charfield-to-foreignkey

Comment: Thanks Bjorn! That's so straightforward, I'm questioning why I didn't think of that myself