# error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type bytea to boolean

Tags: django, django-models

i want to change bytea type to boolean in is_reply field and migrate it but i can not do it even i delete model. i registerd this model in admin panel. i use postgresql

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='ucomments')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='pcomments')
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='rcomments', 
    blank=True, null=True)
    is_reply = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {self.body[:30]}'
```

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/36000084/10951070 even though it's a different change, I think it's the same solution.