# Can't access users in admin after migration

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.5

So I successfully migrated from a profile model to an extended User model. The data migration all worked fine, but I can't access my users from the admin, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'mydb.app_myuser_groups' doesn't exist")
```

All I have defined in `models.py` is the following:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    isSpecial = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

having followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15059338/319618). Is there more I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Might be a dumb question but: does app_myuser_groups exist in the mydb database ?

Comment: @Steve Well no, but I'm wondering why the admin thinks it should be.

Answer (score 1):

See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904046/migrating-existing-auth-user-data-to-new-django-1-5-custom-user-model/15059338?noredirect=1#comment23366051_15059338) and modify step 4 to look like this:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration

class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        # Fill in the destination name with the table name of your model
        db.rename_table('auth_user', 'accounts_user')
        db.rename_table('auth_user_groups', 'accounts_user_groups')

    def backwards(self, orm):
        db.rename_table('accounts_user', 'auth_user')
        db.rename_table('accounts_user_groups', 'auth_user_groups')

    models = { ....... } # Leave this alone
```

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractUser` inherits from `PermissionMixin`, which has a `ManyToManyField` to the `Group` model. So there should be a `app_myuser_groups` table in the database. South may be able to create the intermediate table, but I don't know how. What I know is that `syncdb`ing after having removed `app_myuser` should work, even though your migration would be shredded.

This question about [adding a through table in a migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063357/adding-a-through-table-to-django-field-and-migrating-with-south) should give you more insight.

Comment: Having done my migrations via `rename_table`, can I just use this approach with the other `auth` tables? I'm surprised this hasn't been covered elsewhere...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not at ease with South migrations. I have only one site in production (made at a time when I didn't know well about DRY and South), and my other sites are often DB-reset.

Comment: I have taken a look at `migrate_table` and I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use it for the other tables, even the intermediate ones. One other thing, maybe too dificult, would be to change the `groups` field and add a `db_table` argument, pointing to an existing intermediate table.