# Change django model package registration

Tags: django

Is there a way to change the package registration in a django model?

Let's say we have a model named:

```
app_alpha.models.Page
```

I would like no transform it into

```
app_beta.models.Page
```

and have makemigrations create the proper table.

Comment: duplicated question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862979/easiest-way-to-rename-a-model-using-django-south

Comment: It is not duplicated. Both models are going to exist in parallel