# Rename Django model

Tags: python, django, migration

I've just started working with Django, and when setting up my models and db I picked a name which I would like to change now. Is it OK to just edit `models.py` (rename the class), then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on it? I have a table set up in the db (SQLite), but no entries yet.

I'm new to database migration too. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175106/renaming-modelstables-in-django) cover what I want to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that model referred by other models? Did you have a migration already generated from the original schema?

Comment: No, there's a single model, so no references to it from anything else. I have called `makemigrations` and `migrate`, and have a 0001_initial.py file under /migrations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After renaming of model in the models.py, run `makemigrations`. The question should appear "Did you rename the xxx model to yyy? [y/N]" Press *y* and it will be enough in your case.

**UPD:**
 In general, you should run `makemigrations` and `migrate` every time when you change code in *models.py*. You should manually edit migrations files (created by `makemigrations`) only in few cases, when the Django isn't smart enough to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Then `migrate` to apply that change? That's what's suggested when I run the server. Excuse my ignorance, new to the whole concept of migrations! It seems rather akin to version control.