# Automatically set the table name for a Django Model to the name of its class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Currently, most of my models look like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # model attributes
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'A'

class B(models.Model):
    # model attributes
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'B'
```

Is there a way to do this automatically? I tried adding the meta class after defining the class, but because of how Django handles Meta classes for models, this doesn't work. Am I just stuck defining the Meta classes by hand?

Comment: To automate what? Naming the database table exactly like the class name?

Comment: @willem Let's say that A and B were defined in an app named "myapp". Then the default table name would be "myapp_a" - I would like it to somehow default to "A"

Comment: I think this answered to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175106/renaming-modelstables-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do that but you could do something like:

```
for model in models:
    model._meta.db_table = model.__class__.__name__
```