# Django is deleting and re-creating model instead of rename

Tags: django

```
class ModelA:
    pass

class ModelB:
    model_a = ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

If I want to rename `ModelA` to `ModelANew` here is the strategy Django Follows:

1. Migration 1: Create `ModelANew`
2. Migration 2:

   - Remove field `model_a` from `ModelB`.
   - Add field `model_a_new` to `ModelB`
3. Migration 3: Delete `ModelA`

The obvious downside of this is that the information in the table `modela` is lost. Can this be done with renaming the model? Django obviously did not ask if this was a rename. Is it possible to inform or make it go that route? If not, what would be a strategy to manually code the migration.

Comment: There's an answer to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27175106/renaming-modelstables-in-django

Comment: @TomCarrick: That question is very very old (2014). I doubt Django had migrations then, let alone `RenameModel`.

Comment: It has an answer from 2017. Migrations were introduced in 2015. The answer uses a migration operation that existed then and exists now.

Comment: Also your question seems contradictory to me. The title states "instead of rename" but in the question body it seems clear that you want to rename it rather than dropping the data.

Comment: @TomCarrick: title describes the problem. it is true that I need a rename. The answer that you linked pretty much says "create an empty migration and code it by hand". Doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: Yes it does. It's a simple migration to write. It renames the model. It's _much_ less effort than any other way. What is your problem with it?

Comment: @TomCarrick I don't have a problem with manually writing the migration. If you read the posting, it clearly asks for a strategy to make this happen. You are more than welcome to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Migration 1.**

Create ***ModelANew*** model.

**Migration 2.**

Create [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). Migrate data to new Model.

**Migration 3.**

Delete ***old Model***.

Comment: When would the `ForeignKey` be adjusted?

Comment: This is unnecessary, Django has a `RenameModel` operation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#renamemodel