# Django issue during migrations - lazy reference

Tags: django, django-models

I currently added this model to my app

```
from mainApp.models import modelPatient

class modelBodyParts(models.Model):
    part_name             = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False , default="")
    modelPatient          = models.ForeignKey(modelPatient)
    result                = models.CharField(max_length=3000, unique=False , default="")
```

Now the makemigrations and migrate commands give me the following error

```
 >>python manage.py makemigrations 
 >>python ./manage.py migrate

ValueError: The field interviewApp.modelInterviewAnswers.patients was declared with a lazy reference to 'mainApp.modelpatients', but app 'mainApp' doesn't provide model 'modelpatients'
```

I am not sure what that means. But I do remember that at one point `mainApp.modelpatients` existed and then it was changed to `mainApp.modelpatient`
which still exists.How do I resolve this issue and why is this showing up ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `RenameModel` and `RenameField`. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26241640/57952

Answer (score 15):

For me, this error occurred, because I was swapping a ForeignKey Model from

```
my_field = models.ForeignKey('old.model', ...)
```

to

```
my_field = models.ForeignKey('new.model', ...)
```

---

The solution was to edit the resulting migration manually, and add the latest migration from the `new` app as a dependency:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('old', '0016_whatever'),
        ('new', '0002_latest_migration'),   # Add this line
    ]
```

Comment: I ran into @JamesFranco's same error when trying to undo a `ForeignKey` that was added across apps, and your solution helped. The automatic migration by Django hadn't listed the second app in `dependencies`, so I had to manually add it

Comment: flix, it's wrote me raise CircularDependencyError(
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError

Answer (score 1):

I just had this again on the latest django.  A shared model was renamed (but **not** moved to a new app), and the issue was that it failed to pick up *one* of the other apps that was referencing it.

I can't see why it had an issue with just one app but not the others.  The initial `makemigraitons` went fine, so it just needed to be added to the migration file it created.  After that, subsequent calls to `makemigrations` return "no changes detected", as it should be.

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.5
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        # all the following apps were correctly added as dependencies
        ('supplier',  '0001_initial'),
        ('marketing', '0004_add_some_field'),
        ('devops',    '0002_fix_some_model'),
        ('sales',     '0001_initial'),
        ('warehouse', '0010_set_trained'),
        ('products',  '0005_change_sku_format'),
        ('search',    '0003_remove_bad_data'),

        # Manually add this one, for the app that was missed
        ('left_out',  '0007_change_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name='OldModelName',
            new_name='NewModelName',
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score -6):

delete the entire migration folder and then create it again with the `__init__.py` file and thank me later.

Comment: Probably the worse thing to do, try to throw away the PC and buy a new one then