# error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myApp_audiofile" does not exist when trying to rename Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model called `AudioFile` which is used in several ManyToMany and ManyToOne relations. I tried a simple rename migration (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091130/django-migration-strategy-for-renaming-a-model-and-relationship-fields))

looking like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myApp', '0004_feedback'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel('AudioFile', 'MediaFile')
    ]
```

But instead of it working a get an error traceback looking like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 369, in database_forwards
    to_field,
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 773, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model, new_field, "_fk_%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s"))
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "myApp_audiofile" does not exist
```

When trying to revert to the previous migration I get the following error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0004_feedback, from myApp
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 186, in handle
    changes = autodetector.changes(graph=executor.loader.graph)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 47, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 133, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.concrete_apps
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 222, in concrete_apps
    self.apps = StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models, ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/Users/mac/.virtualenvs/myVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 295, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field myApp.Feedback.lesson was declared with a lazy reference to 'myApp.audiofile', but app 'myApp' doesn't provide model 'audiofile'.
The field myApp.Playlist.audio_files was declared with a lazy reference to 'myApp.audiofile', but app 'myApp' doesn't provide model 'audiofile'.
The field myApp.PlaylistOrder.file was declared with a lazy reference to 'myApp.audiofile', but app 'myApp' doesn't provide model 'audiofile'.
The field myApp.Progress.lesson was declared with a lazy reference to 'myApp.audiofile', but app 'myApp' doesn't provide model 'audiofile'.
```

can anyone explain what is happenning here? Renaming models seems to come with a lot of problems.

I pdbed into the point where it crashes. And the SQL statement crashing is:

```
ALTER TABLE "myApp_playlistorder" ADD CONSTRAINT "myApp_play_file_id_13fdafe4_fk_myApp" FOREIGN KEY ("file_id") REFERENCES "myApp_audiofile" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: check the db if AudioFile table exist in the database or not

Comment: I did. It does exist

Comment: You should check that table name is exactly same as `myApp_audiofile`

Comment: Yes it is. It is automatically being generated by the migrations. I can migrate back and forth otherwise perfectly fine. Only changing the model name breaks everything

Comment: @DavidNathan how do you solve this issue?

Comment: I ended up completely rebuilding the project and changing the layout from single app to multi-app. Maybe I had made some mistakes setting up the project initially