# Renaming user model

Tags: django, database-migration

I'm following the guide provided [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621360/7647113), but I've run into an issue. I'm renaming `myauth.MyUser` to `myauth.User`.

I created my first set of migrations from other apps, converting every ForeignKey to an IntegerField. The migrations were created fine.

I then changed the name or my User model and created a migration, this was also fine.

I created my third set of migrations changing the fields back to ForeignKeys to the new model. These migrations also created fine.

I then manually added dependencies to the migration files, so that the FK -> Int migrations required the previous version of the user app, and the Int -> FK migrations required the latest, renaming migration.

All seems fine, however when I try to run manage.py migrate, I get the following error (a lot of times - for each FK):

```
The field otherapp.Model.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'myauth.user', but app 'myauth' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

What is going on? Is there a way out of this situation?

Comment: Sounds like you put `myapp.user` instead of `myapp.User` in your FK definitions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, nope the models.py files are correct, and the migrations generated successfully (they wouldn't have if I'd misdeclared).