# Better way of linking multiple models in Django [database] - ManyToManyFields, ForeignKey and CharFields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to link the `Subject` model with `Class` in such a way that every student belonging of `Class` model will have same subjects included by user in `Subject models` linked via `connect_class`.

Inside models.py of `school` app.

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import School


class Class(models.Model):
    connect_school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    class_list = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.class_list

class Subject(models.Model):
    connect_class = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subjects = models.CharField(max_length=95, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subjects
```

Inside models.py of `student` app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import nepali_datetime
from school.models import Class, Subject
from accounts.models import School
connect_school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
...name,gender, etc. ...
Class = models.ForeignKey(Class, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)
```

Inside models.py of `accounts`.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import nepali_datetime

# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    ...
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    ....
```

Comment: The renaming ideas for Django are give here: [Django Renaming IDEAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091130/django-migration-strategy-for-renaming-a-model-and-relationship-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

First, migrate the base models so that they don't make any conflicts. For you care you need to migrate `School` models because this model is linked with `Foreign Key` with various other model.

```
python manage.py migrate school
```

`school` is the app_name of your Djang app.

**Step 2:**

After that you need to migrate other branches of your model.