# How to rename Table name in Django?

Tags: django

I just created a model named `Carts` and now I want to rename it to `Cart` only, how do I do it?
I have tried doing this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

and then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But its not reflecting the change in the database table:
I am seeing the database as:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_name> 0001
```

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried changing the `db_table` property of `Meta` class of your model?

Comment: @Nayan How to change `db_table`?

Comment: posible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862979/easiest-way-to-rename-a-model-using-django-south

Comment: @ShubhamKushwah see the documentation here  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#db-table You can set the table name in `db_table` option

Comment: In my case, I had to rename the table(via `db_table` option) and not the model name. I simply changed the `db_table` value and ran `makemigations` and `migrate`. The table rename was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe change the model name in models.py file and run makemigrations and the migrate.

Comment: I had to do what @rajkris said, but I dropped the database and let "migrate" do their job